# Is it possible to extend the lifetime of the CraftSessionId cookie?

Tags: session, cookies, expiration

I would like to extend the lifetime of the CraftSessionId cookie. Is this possible and if so, where can I change the value?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft's `CraftSessionId` cookie is simply the [PHP Session cookie](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) renamed and by default it's terminated when the browser is closed.

Craft currently doesn't expose any way to alter that behavior, but you can always make a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com)!